# "Are not ... and ..." grammar confusion

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I recently read this sentence:

> Compared to other emotions, such feelings are not treated as special and strong.

and wasn't sure if it was ambiguous or not. Which of these are correct interpretations?

> 1. Compared to other emotions, such feelings are (not treated as special) and (strong)
> 2. Compared to other emotions, such feelings are (not treated as) (special and strong)

Comment: It _is_ inherently ambiguous, but the heavily default sense is your second. A Gricean maxim demands that the first meaning should be clarified: 'Compared to other emotions, such feelings are not treated as special, and are strong.' or 'Compared to other emotions, such feelings are strong and not treated as special.' Though I'd expect the coordinator to be 'but'.